# Reverse a string with users input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I decided to take on some programming projects and decided to follow this guide:
https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78802-martyr2s-mega-project-ideas-list/

I started with the first project, which is to reverse a string, pretty simple stuff as you can find out how to do that in the documentation. IE.

```
txt = "Hello World"[::-1]
print(txt)
dlroW olleH



s = "health" [::-1]
print(s)
htlaeh
```

And So on... There's two questions really. In this guide i'm not to sure if they just wanted you to reverse the string. It seems like they want Input? For the user to Enter the String.

In this case i thought it might be something like this:

```
string = Input("Enter a string")
print(s [::-1])
```

How ever this did not work, Not to sure how to implement this in Python 3.8.2. Could someone let me know and how they did it that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: " In this guide i'm not to sure if they just wanted you" - it looks like your "guide" is a post on some forum; you could participate *there* and ask for clarification. But it seems pretty straightforward. "How ever this did not work" - you need to explain what went wrong, or we can't help you.

Comment: It "did not work" because you printed a variable `s` that had not been defined: you assigned the input to `string`, not to `s`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a space between s and the indices you want. You also have two variable names, s and string. Choose one. Finally, `Input` must be lowercase. Change it to this:

```
string = input("Enter a string")
print(string[::-1])
```

Comment: The space is immaterial, and there is no requirement that the input be lower-case.  Please test such assertions before you post them here.

Comment: @Prune, *"there is no requirement that the input be lower-case"*. He is talking about `input()`.

Comment: Ah -- I see it now -- lack of clear typography.

Comment: @Prune You're right that the space technically doesn't matter (I though it did tbh), but it breaks PEP 8 to put the space

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement needs some modifications.
Here it goes-
print(string[: :-1])